# Getting jargon before actual data when printing char pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a program that implements the Alberti Cipher, and when testing, the final print always gives a string of jargon before the actual encryption. Right now its printing \x80\x16G\xbf\xfe\x7fKHOORZRUOG, with KHOOR..... being the actual encryption. Any help appreciated :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int letterToNumber(char letter){
    char str[2] = { letter }; 
    int num = strtol( str, NULL, 36 ) - 10;
    return num;
}

int getSize (const char * s) {
    const char * t;
    int size = 0;
    for (t = s; *t != '\0'; t++) {
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}

char numToChar(int numInp){
    numInp=numInp+65;
    char returnChar=(char)numInp;
    return returnChar;
}

void encrypt_alberti(const char *message,const char *inner_ring, int            initialShift,int periodicShift,int periodLength,char **result){
    //sets initial shift
    int numArray[25];
    int count=0;
    int shiftCount=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        numArray[i]=(i+initialShift)%26;
    }
    //encrypts each character and prints
    int messageSize=getSize(message);
    char encryptedMessage[messageSize];
    for(int i=0; i<messageSize;i++){
        count++;
        if(periodicShift!=0){
            if(count%periodicShift==0){
                shiftCount++;
            }
        }
        else{
            periodLength=0;
        }
        char toBeEncrypted=message[i];
        int charNumber=letterToNumber(toBeEncrypted);
        int encryptedNum=numArray[(charNumber+(shiftCount*periodLength))%26];
        char encryptedChar=numToChar(encryptedNum);
        strncat(encryptedMessage, &encryptedChar, 1);
    }
    char* p1=malloc(sizeof(encryptedMessage));
    strcpy(p1,encryptedMessage);
    *result=p1;

} 
void main(void) {
    const char *example_message = "HELLOWORLD";
    const char *example_inner = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char *encrypted_message = NULL;
    encrypt_alberti(example_message, example_inner, 3, 0, 1, &encrypted_message);
    printf("message is %s\n", encrypted_message);
    printf("-----------------");
    free(encrypted_message);
}
}
```

Comment: About jargon: What does _"being the actual encryption"_ mean?

Comment: `getSize()` doesn't count the null terminator. You need to add 1 when using that as the size of `encryptedMessage`. You also need to initialize it to have a null terminator before you can use `strncat()`.

Comment: There's no need to use `strncat()` like this. Just increment an index variable and assign `encryptedMessage[i] = encryptedChar;`

Comment: And `letterToNumber()` seems to be overcomplicated. Just use `return letter - 'A';`

Comment: For reference, what you're seeing is "gibberish", not "jargon"...